# Problems with gulp and ng-annotate

Tags: angularjs, gulp, ng-annotate

I'm using gulp for my project. While saving the changes made in my Controller, it is not getting updated in my app.js(which contains all the .js code that i have used). In my command prompt, I get this as the result while saving the js file.

[image]

Suggestions for this problem are invited.

Comment: Please create task like `jshint` than execute it and check is your code correct.

Comment: It will be useful if you will show your gulp file...